# Unable to debug NuGet package using Source Link with Bitbucket Cloud

Tags: nuget-package, bitbucket-cloud, sourcelink

Has anyone had any luck getting Source Link to work when using Bitbucket Cloud as the repo with 2 factor and SSH auth enabled?

I've followed all of the provided guidelines on both the NuGet package and consuming end of things.  Symbols are loading just fine, and path of source files looks correct, but the debugger is unable to access them, reporting a 404.  It would appear to be some sort of authentication issue.